# Add new textline having double quotes using sed

Tags: sed

Trying to add new textline having double quotes using sed.

Original file contents:

```
case String of
        "line1"  -> 10;
        "line2"  -> 20;
        _        -> 32
 end.
```

After adding new text, should look like:

```
case String of
            "line1"   -> 10;
            "line2"   -> 20;
            "newline" -> 30;
            _         -> 32
end.
```

Tried with command:

> sed -i '3i "newline"  -> 30;' filename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest with GNU sed:

```
sed -i '4i \        "newline" -> 30;' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested with GNU sed (4.2.2):

```
sed -i '3a\        "newline" -> 30;' input.txt
```

Before:

```
case String of
        "line1"   -> 10;
        "line2"   -> 20;
        _         -> 32
end.
```

After:

```
case String of
        "line1"   -> 10;
        "line2"   -> 20;
        "newline" -> 30;
        _         -> 32
end.
```